# Remove comma only at the end of pandas column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I only want to remove the comma at the end of the pandas column value, how can I accomplish this?

```
value 
apple,
orange, 
banana,pineapple,
grapes,tomato,
```

How can I accomplish this?

Expected outcome

```
value 
apple
orange
banana,pineapple
grapes,tomato
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and `$` to indicate the end of the string.

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace('(,$)', '', regex = True)
print(df)

# If you want to get multiple ',' and repalce with ''
# df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['grapes,tomato,', ',', ',,,']})
# df['value'].str.replace('([,]*$)', '', regex = True)
```

---

```
              value
0             apple
1            orange
2  banana,pineapple
3     grapes,tomato
```